# Create XML structure and insert objects from antoher XML

Tags: xml, xslt, groovy

I need to create/convert a XML structure into another XML structure. This is the response structure i get from the source. The number of "Users" is variable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <User>
    <person>
      <person_id>1234</person_id>
    </person>
  </User>
  <User>
    <person>
      <person_id>5678</person_id>
    </person>
  </User>
</Response>
```

The target structure is supposed to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Body xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <queryResponse xmlns="urn:test.com" xmlns:ns2="urn:example.com">
    <result>
      <object>
    <id>1234(*person_id from source message*)</id>
    <type>Employee</type>
    <person>*here the whole person number 1 object from source XML must be inserted*</person>
    <execution_timestamp></execution_timestamp>
    <version_id></version_id>
      </object>
      <object>
        <id>5678(*person_id from source message*)</id>
    <type>Employee</type>
    <person>*here the whole person number 2 object from source XML must be inserted*</person>
    <execution_timestamp></execution_timestamp>
    <version_id></version_id>
      </object>
      <numResults>*number of Users from source XML must be inserted here(in this case 2)*</numResults>
    </result>
  </queryResponse>
</S:Body>
```

This task is extremly complicated and I would be happy if anyone could give me any suggestions. I need to solve this with groovyscript if possible. Otherwise XSLT.

I have tried to create the structure of the target XML as a String and then manually concatenate the "person" objects from the source XML into the structure. But the iteration over the dynamic number of the Users is where I have no idea how to solve it. Especially since it has to be done from certain nodes into certain nodes. I do not know how to dynamically create the number of nodes/objects in the target dependent on the number of "User" nodes in the source.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: _"I need to create/convert a XML structure into another XML structure."_ - XSLT ! booom. There, I said it first.

Comment: I don't know anything about groovy, but this is a simple task for XSLT.

Comment: Since groovy is in the Java ecosystem: Maybe this helps: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/transformingXML.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using XSLT :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <S:Body xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <queryResponse xmlns="urn:test.com" xmlns:ns2="urn:example.com">
        <result>
          
          <xsl:for-each select="Response/User">
            <object>
              <id>
                <xsl:value-of select="person/person_id"/>
              </id>
              <type>Employee</type>
              <person>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="person/*"/>
              </person>
              <execution_timestamp></execution_timestamp>
              <version_id></version_id>
            </object>
          </xsl:for-each>
          
          <numResults>
            <xsl:value-of select="count(Response/User)"/>
          </numResults>
        </result>
      </queryResponse>
    </S:Body>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- Modify elements to new namespace. -->
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}" namespace="urn:test.com">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You might need to make sure the namespaces are handled properly in your output.

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/948CNrP/4

Comment: Hi Sebastien, thank you very much for the quick answer. It works 99%, there is just one small flaw i am trying to solve. You copy the "person" source node into the target "person" node. Unfortunately it creates a subnode in "person" with the name "<person xmlns=""> " and copies the content there. Any idea how to get rid of that, so that "object/person" structure is exactly the same as in the source?

Comment: I updated my answer, I'm guessing this is what you want.

Comment: @Sebastien: you mean probably `<xsl:value-of select="person/person_id"/>`, not `<xsl:value-of select="person_id"/>` which doesn't return anything.

Comment: I have to apologize Sebastien, I made a mistake in my original explanation. The "User" node contains a "person" node. I want to copy the "person" node and all its children into the target XML. This works fine with your original solution, but it adds an extra node with xmlns="". So the target looks like <user><person xmlns=""><person><name>..." instead of "<user><person><name>.... I hope I explained it more clearly now. copy-of is the function that i need, it just creates this extra stuff i dont need.

Comment: @Phalanx That is because your input XML is not bound to a namespace, and your output XML is bound to namespaces. So when you copy the element, it outputs xmlns="" to indicate the fact that it belongs to no namespace (empty). If you want the person element and its descendants to be bound to the new namespace then an additional step is needed. See updated answer.

Comment: @Sebastien Yes, it works perfectly now! I learned a lot from this, thank you so so much! You are a wizzard with this stuff. :)

Comment: @Phalanx Thanks, glad it helped. I am getting better, but there are real masters of XSLT here on SO from which I have learned a whole lot.